# webpack-cli init "TypeError: env.run(...).on is not a function"

Tags: javascript, macos, webpack

I'm doing a JavaScript tutorial online. I'm using webpack-cli version 2.0.14.

When I type `webpack-cli init` on bash the following error shows up:

```
TypeError: env.run(...).on is not a function
    at modifyHelperUtil (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/utils/modify-config-helper.js:40:25)
    at initializeInquirer (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/commands/init.js:22:10)
    at initialize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/index.js:20:41)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack.js:45:26
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/webpack.js:514:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1147:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1167:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:996:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:896:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
```

the `webpack-cli init` was working before I tried to fix another error by installing and uninstalling webpack-cli@2.0.14. I tried deleting and creating my project folder from scratch multiple times. But the problem still persists.

my node version is 13.12.0
npm is 6.14.4
BTW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're doing the code with mosh oop in javascript course since I am and also had this problem today, and thats the version of webpack he uses in the video. I think it's a version compatibility issue since that version of webpack is a couple of years old now. The configuration I found that worked is:

- node 12.16.2
- npm 6.14.4
- webpack-cli 3.3.11

That will get you past that error message, but after that i got 2 further error messages which I'll detail here just in case. The first is that when I then tried to run `webpack-cli/init` it asks you if you wants to install `@webpack-cli/init` and after selecting yes it did run for a while but errored out with a new error message (followed by a stack trace):

```
Error: spawn npm ENOENT
```

I then successfully installed the latest version of the latest version of `@webpack-cli/init` (0.3.0) with the command `npm install @webpack-cli/init`. This allowed me to run `webpack-cli init` without asking me to install `init` but i got a new error message:

```
TypeError: init isn't a valid name.

It should be prefixed with 'webpack-scaffold', but have different suffix.
```

This seems to be a bug in webpack, as explored here https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/1127. If you don't want to read through that the solution that worked for my is downgrading `@webpack-cli/init` with `npm install -D @webpack-cli/init@0.2.2`. I could then finally successfully run `init` with `npx webpack-cli init`.

Comment: Thanks for responding Louis. I was stuck and frustrated with this for a while and just skipped it. So I just moved on to the React course. I will definitely come across this problem again and I will use this as reference.

Comment: No worries. Yes it was quite a frustrating one for me too as it's one of those ones where trying to debug the error messages is a bit of a fool's errand, so had to use some intuition. Hope it helps when you come back to it.

Answer (score 4):

Came here after Mosh's video as well.

This worked for me :

1. npm i -g webpack webpack-cli @webpack-cli/init@0.2.2
2. webpack-cli init

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this course too, and I had the same problem.
I used Louis's tip and it worked!
My node version is a bit different.

- node 12.16.0
- npm 6.14.4
- webpack-cli 3.3.11

I downgraded webpack-cli/init to 0.2.2 and the error is gone.

Thanks for that!